# Get All td from tr using VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

[image]
[image]

I have a tr which is a object and has td. I want to get all td in another object variable tblTD. For that i used `Set tblTD = tr.getelementsbytagname("td")`. But when i check the lenght of tblTD it shows as 0. Can someone suggest how this can be done. Kindly refer the images attached. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've set `tr` with the `getElementsByTagName` function, then you'll need to iterate through each tr object to get the child td objects (or you can just reference a single one):

```
Dim td As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim tr As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim trObj as MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
Dim tdObj as MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement

Set tr = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
For Each trObj In tr
    Set td = trObj.getElementsByTagName("td")
    For Each tdObj in td
        'do something with each td object'
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question is when i use **Set tblTD = tr.getelementsbytagname("td")** the variable tblTd lenght is o. I have a tr object with has td. Why i cannot use getelementsbytagname ? o

Comment: What is the output of `Debug.Print tr.outerHTML` in the first loop of the `For Each` block?

Comment: the first two rows are header. i realised looking at outerHTML. Set tblTD = tr.getelementsbytagname("th") worked for me. Thanks