# How to write if function for more than one row on website table HTML

Tags: html, vba, excel, html-table

DataGridReservations is a table. I am running a search by row.

My VBA works for one row. Is Is there a way to loop this VBA code to search each row in the table? Maybe by increasing the Item(2) in xobj1 = .... by 1 for each loop?

```
Dim xobj1 As Object
Set xobj1 = IE.Document.getElementById("DataGridReservations").getElementsByTagName("tr").Item(2)
Set xobj1 = xobj1.getElementsByTagName("td")
    If Range("B1").Text = xobj1.Item(9).innertext Then
    Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row)) = xobj1.Item(3).innertext
    Else
    Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row)) = "0"
    End If
```

**REWRITE AFTER COMMENTS**

I'm now getting an object does not support property or method

```
Dim xobj1 As Object
Dim xobj2 As Object
Dim colRows As Object
Set colRows = IE.Document.getElementById("DataGridReservations").getElementsByTagName("tr")
    For i = 0 To colRows.Length - 1
        Set xobj1 = colRows.Item(i)
        Set xobj2 = colRows.getElementsByTagName("td")
        If Range("B1").Text = xobj2.Item(9).innertext Then
        Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row)) = xobj2.Item(3).innertext
        Else
        Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row)) = "0"
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: You can loop through the collection returned by the call to `getElementsByTagName("tr")`  (ignoring the first instance).  Eg. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555513/get-all-td-from-tr-using-vba-code

Comment: Right, I was just thinking maybe there was a way to write the 2 as a formula like x+1 where x is the active item number. and just loop through the list until I ran out of tr elements in the table.

(1.e the first loop would set item(2), the 2nd loop would set item(3), etc.)

Comment: To reorganize, I also wrote this question
http://stackoverflow.com/q/20255214/3023445

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop through the rows with a counter, you can do it like this:

```
Set colRows = IE.Document.getElementById("DataGridReservations").getElementsByTagName("tr")
For i = 0 to colRows.Length -1
    Set xobj1 = colRows.Item(i)
    'Your code
Next
```

The index starts at '0'. Therefore the counter runs to '.Length -1'

*Edited, following revised question:*

```
Dim xobj1 As Object
Dim xobj2 As Object
Dim colRows As Object

Set colRows = IE.Document.getElementById("DataGridReservations").getElementsByTagName("tr")
    For i = 0 To colRows.Length - 1
        Set xobj1 = colRows.Item(i)
        Set xobj2 = xobj1.getElementsByTagName("td")
        If Range("B1").Text = xobj2.Item(9).innertext Then
        Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row)) = xobj2.Item(3).innertext
        Else
        Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row)) = "0"
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: inside of your for...next
could i Set xobj1 = colRows.Item(i) ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Or _colRows(i)_. I should have written that :)

Comment: hmmm. object does not support property or method. see question for my rewrite

Comment: Try: Set xobj2 = xobj1.getElementsByTagName("td")

Comment: wait, theres a way to check which line the errors in?

NVM figured out how to do that... that's cool!

the errors in set colRows = .....

Comment: would it be the '.length' ? since my rows aren't actually rows but rather tags.or is '.length' how you call the number of tr tags for the collection of elements retrieved with 'getelementsbytagname()'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42065/discussion-between-jazzyjoop-and-tpj87)

Comment: Hey @JazzyJoop. sorry about that. I found the error its in the line with

            If Range("B1").Text = xobj2.Item(9).innertext Then

Comment: AHHHHHH!!!!! FIGURED IT OUT! you were right all along. the first tr had a column span set in it so technically there was only one item in the first tr but my code had it looking for item(9) which didnt exist. i changed i = 0 to i = 2 since the 3rd row starts the data... THankyou!!!